# WCF client using WS-Security to call java web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

**Log OUTPUT**

> 

```
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature validate
FINE: Reference[#uuid-26810b23-330b-49c0-af30-59c2a8211341-1] is valid: true
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference dereference
FINE: URIDereferencer class name: org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference dereference
FINE: Data class name: org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.ApacheNodeSetData
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.ApacheCanonicalizer transform
FINE: Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.ApacheCanonicalizer transform
FINE: ApacheData = true
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate
FINE: Expected digest: q9/MlLVrhvl21tGGmxuBVh1V4Mc=
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate
FINE: Actual digest: bFCOsfjajqOmn3mWNcMw+HRtyPM=
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature validate
**FINE: Reference[#e23c17af-c76f-4aaf-bc28-33c5261a253d] is valid: false
25/05/2012 2:08:57 PM org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature validate
FINE: Couldn't validate the References**
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:393)
at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:188)
at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:396)
at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:304)
at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:249)
at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:203)
at au.gov.mca.uhi.security.dsig.XWSSDigitalSignatureProcessorTest.testVerifyWithWSS4J(XWSSDigitalSignatureProcessorTest.java:355)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

**SOAP Security Token**

> ```
>  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
>             xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
>   <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-26810b23-330b-49c0-af30-59c2a8211341-1">
>     <u:Created>2012-05-25T03:58:21.289Z</u:Created>
>     <u:Expires>2012-05-25T04:03:21.289Z</u:Expires>
>   </u:Timestamp>
>   <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-bf155ac7-0ca3-459f-acb5-d8acf3a882d4-2"
>                          ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
>   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="e23c17af-c76f-4aaf-bc28-33c5261a253d"
>                       xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
>                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
>     <wsse:Username>user1</wsse:Username>
>     <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">icnriCyW09WOpQABOeQqFEiqxwY=</wsse:Password>
>     <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">wbwf0IRtQBA6fsrmpQd8fA==</wsse:Nonce>
>     <wsu:Created>2012-05-25T13:58:21Z</wsu:Created>
>   </wsse:UsernameToken>
>   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
>     <SignedInfo>
>       <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>       <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
>       <Reference URI="#_1">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>8Po0d4s3JJB1Xh4vdB6+7M/ivoA=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#_2">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>Azl0elmnUzxTSLUuwfWf6DLT8h8=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#_3">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>h1iD7HzEK+uslbPRHjwN2zt7zhc=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#_4">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>WZ3YS9m3NBoROTnEKUEJ/bNmMDw=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#_5">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>k69pykploFPkXhw5ogDHcjcJUI0=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#_6">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>TSr1cnqSoYmoEIURjA5OZB/iyS0=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#uuid-26810b23-330b-49c0-af30-59c2a8211341-1">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>wSsjhUgRFAN3by438s7ZvGSSgCw=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>       <Reference URI="#e23c17af-c76f-4aaf-bc28-33c5261a253d">
>         <Transforms>
>           <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
>         </Transforms>
>         <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
>         <DigestValue>q9/MlLVrhvl21tGGmxuBVh1V4Mc=</DigestValue>
>       </Reference>
>     </SignedInfo>
>     <SignatureValue>t/piYSnEwCIzqMxC0LQs9fxUla2BKA0GkMI4oLLqZdkthCo9LNvxJP8Luf1d91CEETZ5B4FsQI7QtcA+qHya78K5s+mzn8/2zhEGzAYxkaLeDCUvrad10Mlqssh5AhLbxonZ4/7mDs1v5+s7EVqM0tjpc0tHK0vmroNz0qnAxjCZqEEYpK3/uJ4iwO86khk5pQwqArrwUAqV26/8sXi6c5CfoZcGaVzjIKSAuc+ybV0O42c5OECMe+9G5ZJAkRkw+korLSKgeslLZa18+g/x7WMeUmbo9wiPLuT5kdvIkGRpPN22CQYeSblTFly26J5LIaPdZFSBIAOT3bYs6G4bxA==</SignatureValue>
>     <KeyInfo>
>       <o:SecurityTokenReference>
>         <o:Reference URI="#uuid-bf155ac7-0ca3-459f-acb5-d8acf3a882d4-2"/>
>       </o:SecurityTokenReference>
>     </KeyInfo>
>   </Signature>
> </o:Security>
>     <SignatureValue>t/piYSnEwCIzqMxC0LQs9fxUla2BKA0GkMI4oLLqZdkthCo9LNvxJP8Luf1d91CEETZ5B4FsQI7QtcA+qHya78K5s+mzn8/2zhEGzAYxkaLeDCUvrad10Mlqssh5AhLbxonZ4/7mDs1v5+s7EVqM0tjpc0tHK0vmroNz0qnAxjCZqEEYpK3/uJ4iwO86khk5pQwqArrwUAqV26/8sXi6c5CfoZcGaVzjIKSAuc+ybV0O42c5OECMe+9G5ZJAkRkw+korLSKgeslLZa18+g/x7WMeUmbo9wiPLuT5kdvIkGRpPN22CQYeSblTFly26J5LIaPdZFSBIAOT3bYs6G4bxA==</SignatureValue>
>     <KeyInfo>
>       <o:SecurityTokenReference>
>         <o:Reference URI="#uuid-bf155ac7-0ca3-459f-acb5-d8acf3a882d4-2"/>
>       </o:SecurityTokenReference>
>     </KeyInfo>
>   </Signature>
> </o:Security>
> ```

I have tried almost everything I could i have used inspector and encoder to do this but so far no luck, any help will be appreciated. Please

**Current Code:**

```
        AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement securityBindingElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
        securityBindingElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UsernameTokenParameters());
        X509SecurityTokenParameters initiator
                = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial,
                                                                                    SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient);
        initiator.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
        initiator.ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.Internal;

        securityBindingElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = initiator;
        X509SecurityTokenParameters recipient
                = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial,
                                                                                    SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator);
        recipient.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
        securityBindingElement.RecipientTokenParameters = initiator;
        securityBindingElement.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        securityBindingElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128;
        securityBindingElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion
                                .WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
        X509SecurityTokenParameters tokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
        tokenParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
        tokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
        securityBindingElement.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;

        HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
        binding.Elements.Add(securityBindingElement);
        binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8));
        //binding.Elements.Add(new CustomEncoderBindingElement());
        binding.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);
        EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://xya.com"),
                                                                                                                 EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(
                                                                                                                    "Test Location 027 :5657050091"),
                                                                                                                 new AddressHeaderCollection());
        ChannelFactory<DhsUserAuthUploadHposDvaStatementsPortTypeChannel> channelFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<DhsUserAuthUploadHposDvaStatementsPortTypeChannel>(binding, serviceAddress);
        UsernameClientCredentials credentials = new UsernameClientCredentials(new UsernameInfo("user1", "user1"));
        credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
        credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                                                                                 "6c1a76f952028e092cea367d40d6cf5833d9d3a3");
        credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.TrustedPeople,
                                                                                                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                                                                                                 "6c1a76f952028e092cea367d40d6cf5833d9d3a3");
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ClientCredentials));
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(credentials);
        var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        client.upload();
```

I have tried almost everything I could i have used inspector and encoder to do this but so far no luck, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this does not look like the full soap header, I can't see if there is siangture. what I already see is the use of #X509PKIPathv1 which WCF does not support but you may get a way with changing that on a custom encoder. then the username uses created/hash pairs which again is not ootb but you can use this project http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf.aspx or even do it manually as here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4df3354f-0627-42d9-b5fb-6e880b60f8ee

Comment: Hi Yaron, I have used custom Encoder but it just returns the soap message with out any signatures and username token. When i try to add the related information then it some how doesn't look like the original one. I have added header information in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that you need a username token with message digest + created + nonce AND you need it signed. If you have any way to dismiss one of this requirements it will be easier. Otherwise here is a direction, it will require some work.

1. check out [this project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf.aspx). it is your friend to help you create the username token in the requested format.
2. In order to create the security binding element use

   SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement()

   then as you did above add to it the user name token (the one form item #1).

   note you will be required to sepcify a service certificate. you probably don't have or need one,     so just supply any dummy certificate in the service credentials property, it can even be the same one as the client certificate.
3. If you have not done so already decorate your contracts (reference.cs?) with:

   [ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign)]

   since (as it seems from the partial soap envelope) you only use signature and not encryption.

Comment: Hi Yaron, thanks for your quick reply I have already done the points you have told me now the problem is nonce in user name requires "encoding type" attribute which I have already done. Problem is I have to put the same encoding type in binary security token and to change its tag from "o" to   Wsse. How to do it and to change the security tags from o to wsse. Any idea?

Comment: changing o to wsse does not make sense - I would make sure everything else is right, and also any server error before that. Actually I don't know how to do this w/o rewriting wcf security all together. Although for the binary security token - you can change it if you want using a custom encoder (since it is not signed). It is hard to change the other parts which are signed. I don't think the prefix is the issue

Comment: Hi Yaron, I am getting this Message while using encoder. I can see binarysecurity token in it? Any thoughts how can we change binarysecuritytoken? with expected values. Please see out put section above.

Comment: not sure I understand - have you tried the 3 steps I suggested? If not what is your current config and how the output looks? The output section you published above has no security at all

Comment: Yaron, I am able to change the token from encoder but i don't know why it is putting this tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in SOAP envelope... any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: publish the code you use, usually on the XmlDocument / XmlWriter etc you have some property if this should be emitted or not

Comment: Ok I will do that in next 5 hours. Apart from that packet looks good and the only issue now is header has got 2 signature tokens one token has got the references for all signature and one has got reference for body only. Requirement is to have 1. Any idea?

Comment: Set the messageSecurityVersion attribute of the security element to something that starts with wssecutity10

Comment: I can't use wssecurity10 as request has to be in WS11. Is there any other way to get rid of another signature section. Code in customer Encoder which is putting xml tag in soap message is about in current code section.

Comment: the only difference between wss10 and wss11 is the double signature you have, I don't see what it means that you have to use wss11

Comment: The java service we are trying to call only accept soap message with ws11. That's why I can't send ws10 message.

Comment: Yaron, I am using the same username example that you referred me to, Now java service is giving this error. Do you have any idea? `FINE: Reference[#a775eca2-81bd-4364-a2f2-cb4322372315] is valid: false
This usually happens when the element (UsernameToken) is modified after signing.`  I am using `security.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt`. see out put in detail in output section above..

Comment: you are not allowed to change the message with a custom encoder since it is signed. try maybe to change the username when it is created. you have to do it with this project http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf.aspx

Comment: I am already creating username token by using this project. Anything else I can do?

Comment: your encoder changes the message and this is not legal if you have signature. if you want to change something in the username format fo it by changing the code in that oss project that generates the username xml

Comment: Yes you are right I am not using encoder to generate username token. Using this project to generate it for me but some how java service is not accepting it.

Comment: Above I have added Java log output as well as soap request.

Comment: java definetely complains that someone has changed the username token after it was signed. verify the encoder was fully removed, and even in the project code there si nothing that changes it